# best way to get RecycleView detail in another view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm implementing `onClick` on my main layout that contain all my views, in order to pass data to another view e.g:

```
 holder.wholeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         //pass data with something like eventBus and transition to another view 
        }
    });
```

I think there is a better way to do that?

Comment: you want the detail from recycler view row you click on??

Comment: Well, yes @sumit but i think my way not good.

Comment: You want to fire event when click on recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

}
```

and from your activity where you're using your Recycler view use it like this:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, mRecyclerView,
                new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                    // use this position to fetch the data from your list which you used to populate your recylcer view
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

                    }
                }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the list of items from which the recycler view items are made. Now simply use this

```
myList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
```

This will return you the object of the clicked position.

Hope this helps.